# Setting up networking for the first time on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on configuring a physical Windows Server 2008 R2 box.

I have enabled AD/DNS but one of the issues I have is getting connected to the network so I can surf the internet etc.

I have been given a static IP, default gateway, set the FQDN (not related to the operation of the network), and set these values in IPV4 on the one physical NIC. DNS server I have left blank as that will be the local server. I have set the IP of the local server in the DNS tab (http://www.walkernews.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/vista-dns-setting.jpg that tab).

Despite this, the internet does not work and always has the exclamation mark on the network icon to the system tray.

Also, can I uncheck IPV6? How do I know if I need this checked or not?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is plugged into the network? There should be an ethernet cable from the NIC to an ethernet switch.

Comment: I checked this today and this is connected indeed (the switch is next to the server so this was very easy to verify).

Answer (score 1):

You need an entry for the DNS server in your IP configuration.  You can point it to your own server, but your DNS server will need a forwarder to an Internet aware DNS server in order to resolve Internet names.

Comment: Does that mean if DNS was not enabled there would not be an issue?

Comment: @blade If you want AD you have to have DNS running, unless you have another server running DNS for AD but that doesn't sound like it's the case here.  Otherwise you don't need it enabled and you can use the DNS servers provided to you by your host (enter in your IP configuration).

Comment: I see. There's something I am missing because I had AD/DNS running and the details entered but I did something with the adapter(s) (one adapter is disabled but seen in network adapters), and I had internet connectivity. I didn't enter values for DNS in that tab nor did I configure the DNS server for anything (in fact it was not even running).

Comment: @Blade Do you need to run AD?

Comment: Yep. I'm also aware that DNS is required with AD.

Comment: @Blade What are the two adapters for? Is one NIC connected to the Internet and one connected to your internal network?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, your DNS server will need information on the root zones before it can resolve DNS queries itself.  A DNS server you can forward requests is fine, but if you had that you could just point your network DNS settings there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this and other questions you've asked I see that you are very much an entry level person an perhaps should take a couple of steps back and learn some fundamentals before proceeding any further.

The Internet is chock full of tutorials on just about any subject. Not surprisingly, articles and setting up servers are very abundant. Take a break, do some Googling and have a good read of some of those tutorials. You might also consider investing in some of the many good books available. Any time spent learning the basics will be amply rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

Start Task Manager -> Networking Tab.  Is the state "connected"? If not, you have a physical cabling problem.  If yes, start by pinging your gateway address.  If that works try pinging one of your dns name servers.  To test dns, try: ping -a serverfault.com

In general, start with the closest network devices (such as the router) and gradually move further away.